# Add NULL to char double pointer

Tags: c

I am using fork and `execvp(const char *path, char *const argv[]);` to run a child process. From the documentation it states that argv must be `NULL` terminated. However, I am unsure how to do this. Lets say I have an implementation like this (**this is just for simplicity and demonstration!**):

```
// Allocate space
char **argv_list = (char**)calloc(3, sizeof(char*));
argv_list[0] = (char*)calloc(strlen(token1), sizeof(char));
argv_list[1] = (char*)calloc(strlen(token2), sizeof(char));
argv_list[2] = (char*)calloc(strlen(token3), sizeof(char));
// Assign values
strcpy(argv_list[0], token1);
strcpy(argv_list[1], token2);
strcpy(argv_list[2], token3);
```

How would I add an additional `NULL` in the same style as above? With an array of pointers I would do it like this:

```
char *argv_list[] = {"ls", "-l", "..", NULL};
```

I tried it like this and it gave me a segmentation fault. Please le me know what I am doing wrong:

```
// Add NULL pointer
argv_list = (char**)realloc(argv_list, (4 * sizeof(char*)));
argv_list[3] = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(NULL));
strcpy(argv_list[3], NULL);
```

Ps: Please don't tell me that there is a better way of doing this or my implementation is bad. I have to do it like above and this is just for simplicity. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over complicating things I'd have said. Also worth noting that in your code you only initialise 1 of the 3 strings dues to always using argv_list[0]

```cpp
// Allocate space
char **argv_list = (char**)calloc(4, sizeof(char*));
argv_list[0] = (char*)calloc(strlen(token1), sizeof(char));
argv_list[1] = (char*)calloc(strlen(token2), sizeof(char));
argv_list[2] = (char*)calloc(strlen(token3), sizeof(char));
argv_list[3] = NULL;
// Assign values
strcpy(argv_list[0], token1);
strcpy(argv_list[1], token2); //< bug in your code here?
strcpy(argv_list[2], token3); //< bug in your code here?
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, my bad! That worked, thank you!!

Comment: Also note dbush's comment below - missing the extra char for the null terminator for each string.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, forgot to do that!

Comment: @robthebloke: "*missing the extra char for the null terminator*" So why not at least fix it in your own answer?

Answer (score 3):

For the last element in this list, you don't need to allocate any memory.  Just set it to NULL.  Also, be sure to add 1 to each of the `calloc` calls for the tokens to make room for the null terminating byte:

```
// Allocate space
char **argv_list = calloc(4, sizeof(char*));
argv_list[0] = calloc(strlen(token1) + 1, sizeof(char));
argv_list[1] = calloc(strlen(token2) + 1, sizeof(char));
argv_list[2] = calloc(strlen(token3) + 1, sizeof(char));
argv_list[3] = NULL;
// Assign values
strcpy(argv_list[0], token1);
strcpy(argv_list[1], token2);
strcpy(argv_list[2], token3);
```